# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/customers/webs/ni272979_1/Loader/login.php on line 17

Tags: php

```
<?php
$filename = 'install.php';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo ("<center><font color='red'><b>/install.php still exists<br>
After installing please delete install.php</center></font></b>");
} else {
if (isset($_POST['Login'])){
include('config.php');
    if (!mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)) die("Can't connect to database");
    if (!mysql_select_db($db_name)) die("Can't select database");
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' or die(mysql_error());";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count >= 1){
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword");
    header("location: index.php");
    } else {

    }
}
```

?>

I have tried to fix it but not sucsessfuly. I don't know how i can fix it because i am a php noob.

Comment: Please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection).  New code should not be written using the deprecated `mysql_*()` functions. Instead, this is the time to start learning to use `prepare()/execute()` securely with MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Please learn how not to store passwords(plain text for 1): http://youtube.com/watch?v=8ZtInClXe1Q

Comment: If you are working from a particular tutorial, it is _highly advisable_ to find a more recent one. [`session_register()` is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your query. It should be something like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword';";
```

And then you can do something like this.

```
 $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also try using [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) function for CRUD operations.